# How to prevent close-able questions from being listed under "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, hot-questions

Not infrequently, SO questions that get listed in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar are close-able or even already in the process of being voted to be closed.  For instance, earlier today there was a Haskell question that should have been posted to codereview.stackexchange, not SO.

How about a mechanism for not including such questions in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar once they've received a vote or two to be closed?

Comment: It definitely has to be more than 1 vote. Otherwise it's too easy to abusively knock something off the hot questions list just because somebody doesn't like the question.

Comment: @Mysticial "Close votes are not taken into account. Note how this contrasts to [close votes impact in twitter bot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139857/twitter-bots-share-posts-with-closevotes-on-them)... Close votes on the question should reduce the total hotness of the question by 20% (so a closed question would have a 0 hotness score)..." ([Reorder questions picked for hot list...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216260/165773))

Comment: Oh, the hotness.

Comment: Which, does actually happen. Jealous user: "Not fair! Why does this have so many votes? Close vote." I wouldn't want a single user to be able to single-handedly clear the hot questions list.

Comment: related: [...penalize hot questions having 3-4 close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237391/165773) at MSE. Granted, it's focused on smaller sites, but comments from SO regulars over there suggest that they want it too