# Why was this +23/-3 question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, hot-questions

I noticed that a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28850432/1782465) where I had an answer was recently deleted; the question's score at time of deletion was +20, vote count +23/-3. I would really like to understand the rationale for this deletion.

The only thing I can think of is that for about two weeks, it was closed as a duplicate. It was reopened recently (after the deletion), which I agree with; it was *not* a duplicate of the question linked. Still, my understanding is that duplicates, even if closed validly, are useful as signposts, so why delete it?

I have no problem with the question staying deleted if that's community consensus, but I would most certainly like to understand the why of it.

Comment: It has been undeleted and reopened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I noticed. But this was not a "please reopen" cry in disguise; I would genuinely like to know why it was closed.

Comment: high score is because [it was featured in hot questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287168/839601). This probably also explains a higher than average "meta effect" - such questions are exposed to many users having 3K privileges to close and 10K privileges to delete

Comment: @gnat: the post was deleted by "the usual suspects"; I am not sure that many of the deletions they execute are necessary or warranted, to be honest. I strongly suspect that the [10k+ tools deletion tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) is involved here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ['Jealous user: "Not fair! Why does this have so many votes? Close vote."'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253912/how-to-prevent-close-able-questions-from-being-listed-under-hot-network-questio#comment16410_253912) It can work about the same way for voters to delete

Comment: @gnat: right; I see what you mean. Deleting the post because you disagree it is hot is.. petty.

Comment: More than one thing went wrong here, the very high exposure you got and the completely inappropriate gold badge hammer dup closure certainly did not help.  But you could probably have saved yourself some grief by adding some usage advice to your solution.  There is at least a *bit* of responsibility attached to posting an unusual hack like this.  Theoretically anybody that reads it would just think "ah, interesting hack but I'll never use it".  But there will certainly be a subset that thinks "ugh, what if by newbie team mate starts using it!"

Comment: @HansPassant Good point about adding a "use with caution" section. I will do that.

Comment: @HansPassant Added the disclaimer.

Comment: @Hans Passant: You mean a subset that thinks "this looks awesome, I'm going to use it!"

Comment: Right, furthermore inspired by the large number of votes.  So it must be awesome and the Right Thing to do.

Comment: @gnat never assume malice in those who just want to pick up the trash

Comment: @JanDvorak [blame Mysticial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253912/how-to-prevent-close-able-questions-from-being-listed-under-hot-network-questio#comment16410_253912) - it was his comment I quoted... although he also doesn't seem to insist that this is always the case

Comment: It is a duplicate, but I'm too lazy to find the original question(s)/

Comment: Or not.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/25513374/103167  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15090209/103167  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23179/2150  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20861231/103167  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14782169/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd say the answer is indeed duplicating some other answers (of which I was not aware when writing it), but the question is not. The question was explicitly asking about introducing an operator represented by a character not currently in the C++ syntax. I only offered the named operators as a workaround.