# Is the quality of 'Hot Network Questions' a concern to others?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, hot-questions

I've noticed a trend across multiple SE sites where the 'hot questions' that appear in the right column tend to be rather poor questions for the SE site they were posted on. They are often purely subjective, only tangentially related, and often questions that have several close votes already by the time they become hot questions.

I don't know the full history of the 'hot question' feature. I assume it was perhaps to cross-promote SE sites and get more exposure for them.

If that's the case, does anyone share the concern that these questions are often poor examples of the types of questions that are being posted (or people would like to have posted) on said sites?

If so, any thoughts on suggestions to fix it?

UPDATE:

Another example from today:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/what-is-a-clove-of-garlic

This is a highly up-voted 'hot question'. It's also a question that can be answered extremely quickly via a Google search.

I'm increasingly finding that I'm more likely to be disappointed clicking on a hot question than pleased in terms of quality. :/

Comment: Seems to me that "Hot Questions" should be driven by activity, which is what makes them "hot questions". Not sure why that would be confusing. They're not called "Moderator's Picks" or "Questions moderator-selected to advertise SE sites", or "Carefully chosen, non-typical, and censored questions to show other site activities", after all (and I'd suspect making them any of those things would ruin the usefulness).

Comment: @KenWhite my concern isn't that people confuse what 'hot question' means, but rather that hot questions are very often poor questions. My theory is that they get a lot of upvotes from outside the sphere of subject matter experts that would typically be voting on said site. One proposal would be to retain them as user-chosen hot-questions, but allow moderators to remove ones that, while hot, are simply poor indicators of the type of content on the SE site in question.

Comment: If they're hand-picked, they're not "Hot Questions". The topic isn't "Selected Content Types" - it's **hot questions**. I can't believe you seriously think that *currently very active* should instead mean *currently active but filtered, moderator picked, carefully hand-selected to show the most favorable impression*. Sort of similar to North Korea's *all the news that's fit to be shown according to the rules of the current regime* attitude.

Comment: Why post this here and not MSE? Seems more suited to the general meta.

Comment: @KenWhite again, that's merely one suggestion. Like I already said in my comment, one proposal would be to retain them as user-chosen questions.  I can't believe you seriously can't consider the other suggestions or simply address the concern (do you agree with it or not?). Also North Korea? Dude?

Comment: @ChrisHayes What is MSE? Maybe that is the better place.

Comment: Also: downvoters, I'd love to hear YOUR OPINION rather than just a vote. :)

Comment: @DA The [cross-site meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ChrisHayes Aha! That would make a whole lot more sense. Any moderators here that can migrate? (I'll flag it)

Comment: You're suggesting that "most active questions on a site" be "most active questions on the site (if moderators or some users approve it as acceptable 'most active" activity)". How is that different than what happens in some dictatorships? "All the news that's fit to print (as long as we think you should know about it)" isn't "news".

Comment: @KenWhite you keep reading one single sentence over and over again. I don't know where to go with that. I get it, you don't agree with that one sentence. And you hate North Korea. Duly noted.

Comment: I'm reading your entire post, not one sentence. I object to anything that attempts to make something pretend to be what it's not. If the content is intended to show "most active content", it should be the actual "most active content", not "most active content we choose to be favorable". If something is represented to be "current news", it should be current news and not "current news if it meets my standards of what you should know". I don't agree with your entire concept that "hot questions" should somehow be anything other than "those questions currently most active".

Comment: @KenWhite Again, I get it. You disagree. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Just to point it out (quoting you): *Also: downvoters, I'd love to hear YOUR OPINION rather than just a vote.* Apparently not the case. Perhaps you should restate it as "I'd love to hear YOUR OPINION as long as it agrees with mine". :-)

Comment: @KenWhite  I was hoping to have a broader discussion about whether or not the concern I had was shared. I don't really care if the questions are called 'hot' or 'popular' or whatever. Seems that the purposes was to help cross-promote SE sites. It seems that if that was the goal, there'd be some shared desired that said questions were indicative of the subject matter/quality of the site in general. That a question is 'popular' does not appear to correlate with it 'being good'. I'm not proposing the site be taken over by South Korea. Just seeing if there's a shared concern about the question...

Comment: ...quality on said side bar. I get that you disagree that if it's a list of questions that it should be a list chosen by moderator. But that's just a part of what I was hoping to bring up. I don't disagree with you that if it's a list of *popular* questions that a *dictator* should be the one to choose them. :)

Comment: (In the end, it doesn't really matter. Seems few people in here want to even discuss the issue....I do appreciate you sharing your opinion, though, Ken.)

Comment: Perhaps you should restate it then, so that it's more clear that you're wanting to have "Hot Network Questions" changed to something else like "Representative Network Questions" or "Current Representative Questions" or "Sample Network Questions". My objection is to having something that purportedly represents activity that's "hot" be something other than that activity. "Currently trending" should mean something different than "Currently hand-picked".

Comment: @KenWhite fair point. I'll try and rewrite the post.

Comment: @KenWhite how's that for a rewrite? I tried to avoid making any specific suggestions and focus more on the concern than solution.

Comment: I think your rewrite is very good. It more clearly expresses what I think you probably intended from the onset. I'll reverse my downvote; this is a much better idea for discussion. Thanks for listening. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your perseverance with me. :)

Comment: see [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287168/839601) "...You see, none of above seems to suggest that hot questions are selected based on quality or usefulness."

Comment: one particular concern is laid out in [How to prevent close-able questions from being listed under “Hot Network Questions”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253912/839601)

Comment: @gnat from that first link: "We want to focus on showing them the kind of content they might find on our sites" = that is the problem I think we have as a lot of these hot questions are explicitly NOT the kind of content the sites want to have on the site.

Comment: @DA. oh, that's a matter with fuzzy "we" used over there. "We" in that sentence is Stack Exchange team - everything I ever seen done in [discussions about these matters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-questions) was about what SE team wants, not about sites communities

Comment: @gnat ah...interesting. So it sounds like the SE team doesn't share this concern that the communities themselves may have?

Comment: So, on second read, I guess the concern I'd like the SE team to maybe consider is that these *aren't* the types of questions one might find on said sites. They're actually anomalies and just as often an example of the kind of question you *wouldn't* see on those sites due to the community closing them.

Comment: as far as I know, major (maybe even the only) concern SE team has in this hot-questions business is ["repeated clicks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222993/165773)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question isn't about Stack Overflow, but Stack Exchange in general. It should be migrated to http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I agree, it should be migrated.

Comment: Make sure you read [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/213963) to have an idea of what Stack Exchange is trying to do with that part of the side bar.

Comment: @MichaelT it appears that there isn't a goal defined yet?

Comment: @DA. they are the buzzfeed of Stack Exchange: "I actually have a slightly different opinion of what "hot" questions are good for: entertainment. When I'm bored, tired of doing actual work or waiting for something to finish running, they're almost always good for a quick - and ideally informative - diversion."

Comment: @MichaelT "the buzzfeed of Stack Exchange" = ha! So true! And sums up my frustration well, I think. I suppose for this question to be answered, someone has to decide what the goal is first. If it's truly to be link bait/buzzfeed quality stuff, then I guess it's succeeding. Alas, I feel it's succeeding to the detriment of many of the SE site's quality.

Comment: @DA. the general consensus on that appears to be various vote manipulation (I've seen in chat rooms when something that is crap gets hot they seek to down vote it to cool it off, or close it, or get a mod to protect it - though many of those things are too late given caching). On MathJax enabled sites, mathjax questions don't show up as hot... so they'll cool them off by editing the title. But yes, it is a concern for many... though other sites seem to relish the attention (poor quality or not - any popularity is good popularity).