# Downvoting - What is the purpose?

Tags: discussion

I've just stumbled across this question which I believe is to be a good question [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041323/css-position-label-text-10px-right-of-the-background-image). Not a great question but I totally understood what he required from the code, I also understand that the problem is simple to solve and details need to be added. But is downvoting a means of scrutiny on the quality of question or scrutiny on the simplicity of the problem? what is the purpose of downvoting on SO?

Comment: You can up vote if you think it is a good question. The people who down voted they thought its not good question.

Comment: My guess is the lack of details on the problem.  He explains his goal, shows his code, but fails to show **exactly** what is wrong with the code.  A user is forced to go to an external website to see the problem.  Questions must be self-contained, so screen shots highlighting exactly what is wrong would be preferable.  But it is only a guess.  We can't really know why people downvoted the question.  For all we know the downvotes are because [Tim lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Comment: @ShaifulIslam one can only assume as much bud.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thankyou. that'll be something i'll pay attention to.

Comment: @BradleyWilson as you see psubsee2003's comment. I think I should down-vote that too.If a user knows that much about css he must knows about padding-left or padding. It seems he posted that code without trying anything.He should not ask people without doing something.

Comment: This extract from one of the answers about sums it up: *"It must also be said that this is seriously basic stuff. Before you come running to StackOverflow on the first problem you encounter, try treating the language with a little respect by studying it properly."*

Comment: Frankly, it looks like a duplicate of [Are high rep users assumed to have 'done their homework'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292082/are-high-rep-users-assumed-to-have-done-their-homework).

Comment: You're welcome to use your voting privileges (up or down) however you see fit. So are others. Apparently there are several people who do not share your feeling that the question is perfectly good. And because it prevents lots of clutter, negative discussion, and squabbling, there is no requirement for anyone to explain why they chose to vote the way they did; voting is intentionally anonymous here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I can explain the reasoning for one third of the current 3 down votes. To run through the down vote tooltip bit by bit:

- **This question does not show any research effort;**: One Google search showed three different answers to the question... ...and they were the top three results.
- **it is unclear**: Do they mean they want the text 10px past the right edge of the background or past the left edge? It is not specified.
- **or not useful**: If they remove the image link, the problem will no longer be complete for future users. Plus, this could already be figured out by finding other questions. It does not provide additional benefit to the Stack Overflow knowledge base.
- **(click again to undo)**: Hopefully, this part is obvious. :)